# Why does the Thread Pool manage threads this way?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, algorithm, threadpool

Joe Albahari provides a [great explanation](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Optimizing_the_Thread_Pool) of the .NET Thread Pool's automatic thread management, and why it works the way it does, in his Threading in C# e-book.

From what I understand, by default, after occupying all of a processor's cores, the thread pool delays the creation of new threads, because if all processor cores are busy doing computations, creating new threads can no longer improve the overall throughput (tasks completed per second) of the application, and new threads are just a waste of system resources.

However, if a task sits in the thread pool queue for too long, the thread pool assumes that a pooled thread is idling or blocked in some way, and tries to take advantage of the downtime by running the task concurrently.

Rather than this "delay" algorithm, wouldn't it make more sense, in many situations, to employ a technique whereby thread pool threads have a special property that signals a "waiting" state? It might look something like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsWaiting = true;
```

The thread pool would create new threads instantly for queued tasks until all processor cores are occupied with *non-waiting* threads. Then, tasks are held in the queue until a thread either finishes, OR signals a waiting state.

This would have a couple benefits. First, if a processor core is idle, tasks are always started the instant they are queued to the pool, with no delay. Second, in an application that runs a lot of computationally-intensive tasks that take more than half a second to complete, the thread pool won't continue to burden the system with unnecessary extra threads.

Of course, there may be some situations in which an application needs to finish tasks within a strict deadline, and can't wait for other tasks to finish first. This algorithm may not work for those applications. Otherwise, I imagine that it will only improve efficiency of multithreaded applications.

What do you think?

Comment: Sure.  But that feature doesn't exist so this is just navel staring.  Having a thread pool thread waste time on I/O completion is a bug.  Removing bugs from a program is a programmer's job, a concurrency analyzer is the tool of choice to find such bugs.

Answer (score 0):

We have this information available in the `Thread.ThreadState` property. But it would not be a good idea for a thread pool to use this information. To use it, we would need communication between threads (the ones in the thread pool, and another gathering the information). That would mean some needs of synchronization, or at least volatile access. Both is really expensive. Thus, we would give a runtime burden to all applications of the ThreadPool, whereas only a few would benefit.

As a programmer, you have to reflect how your thread pool is used. If the standard behavior is not suitable for you, you can tweak the pool. E.g. using `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`, if you know you have a lot of waiting threads. It would not be as automatic as you wish. But your automatization would also not be perfect, since we could have easily too many threads running, when some of the waiting threads wake up simultaneously.

Note, that other thread pools do not have the quite clever extension heurisitc at all, which is build into the C# variant. Normally, you have a fixed number of running threads, and you will never have more than this number running.